# How to force an installer to not reboot after repair?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, reboot, repair

I have an installer written in Wix which sometimes prompts the user to reboot after repair. How can this occur and how to remove this behavior?

Comment: Set logging policy and it will log the repair into %temp%, into a file called MSI<hex string>.log.   https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/223300

Answer (score 3):

Two techniques:

1) Identify the cause of the reboot and avoid it.  ( Examples: stop service, kill process )

2) Suppress reboot using the REBOOT property.  Note repair may not be effective until after the reboot.

1 is usually the best way to go.

Comment: What can cause the reboot?

Comment: Typically a locked file hence why stopping processes that might have file locks.

Comment: Why the repair may not be effective until after the reboot? My installer only deploys some files and write registry keys. In that case is it safe to use the REBOOT property?

Comment: If the installer needed to repair a locked file and the old file was wrong and the new file is correct then the new file won't be available until after the reboot.  I suggest reading up on the Win32 MoveFile function and the PendingFileRenameOperations pattern.

Comment: So if I understand correctly: if a file is locked (typically by being used by another process), the installer will use the PendingFileRenameOperations pattern so that the file is repaired after a reboot. Therefore the installer requests the user to reboot to replace the file correctly. So what does the Win32 MoveFile has to do with it? Does the installer use it to try to move the old file somewhere else and then move the new one to the desired destination?

Comment: Realize that MSI is declarative.  They abstract what needs to be done from how it gets done.  The latter is very seldom documented as you don't need to know.  Presumably the InstallFiles and MoveFiles standard actions use MoveFileEx with the MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT  argument.  You can search StackOverflow for those two words to see how frequently it comes up.

Answer (score 2):

The most common reason for a reboot after repairs is a file was accessed by the installer that the application still had a lock on. This is usually identifiable in the repair logs (sometimes it takes a bit of looking to find the file the installer had trouble with). If you are unable to find the information you need in your logs, post them here and we will take a look at them with you.

Comment: You want to look for these types of messages: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369779(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: It's also quite common for people to have a ScheduleReboot in the setup to force a reboot after first install, but they forget to condition it and so it happens on every repair.

Answer (score 1):

Add this property somewhere relevant in your WXS file, and make sure nothing is overriding the value to something else. This will cause the reboot prompt to not occur *and* not have the reboot occur even if it was detected as necessary when running silently, as silent reboot prompts will automatically trigger the reboot sequence when you don't set this property's value to `"ReallySuppress"`.

`<Property Id="REBOOT" Value="ReallySuppress" />`

You can read up on it here if you like: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371101

Comment: >> Add this property somewhere relevant in your WXS file << I found that I needed to define this property as a child element of Product, after the Package element had been defined.